Rename SharePoint site with Graph API or REST
I am looking for the ability to programmability change the name of a sharepoint site with either Graph API or SharePoint REST (or related powershell modules)
I have tried "Set-PnPWeb" this command seems to change the site title then revert back after a bit.
In the screen shot I want to change "Site Name" (also whats the difference between "Name" and "Site Name"?)

In my case, Rename-PnPTenantSite command worked to change site name and did n't revert back. Could you include that image after reverting back how it looks whether name and site name are same or different?


whats the difference between "Name" and "Site Name"?

Whenever you create team site in SharePoint, Microsoft 365 group will also be created automatically with same name as site. Here, Name refers to Microsoft 365 group name whereas Site Name refers to SharePoint site name.
I have one SharePoint team site named demoteamsite12 with below properties:

In my case, I ran below PowerShell commands to change site name and got response like this:
$oldSiteURL = "‎https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/‎‎demoteamsite12"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $oldSiteURL -Interactive

$newSiteName = "teamsite12"
$newSiteUrl = "https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/teamsite12"

Rename-PnPTenantSite -Identity $oldSiteUrl -NewSiteUrl $newSiteUrl -NewSiteTitle $newSiteName -Wait

Response:

When you check the site properties in SharePoint Admin Portal now, only site name and site address will be changed as below:

Alternatively, you can also below PowerShell script to achieve the same if above does not work:
Install-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -force

# Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url https://xxxxxxxxx-admin.sharepoint.com

# Define the old site URL and the new site URL
$oldSiteUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/teamsite12"
$newSiteUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/demosite12"

# Define the new site title
$newSiteName = "demosite12"

# Start the site rename operation
Start-SPOSiteRename -Identity $oldSiteUrl -NewSiteUrl $newSiteUrl -NewSiteTitle $newSiteName

Response:

When I checked the same in SharePoint Admin Portal after few minutes, site name changed successfully as below:

Reference:
Start-SPOSiteRename (Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell) | Microsoft 

Do you know of a way to change the site name without changing the URL? I could always change the url then change back. rather not if i dont have to.

In that case, you can just change site title using Start-SPOSiteRename -Identity $Url -NewSiteTitle $newSiteTitle or Set-PnPWeb -Title $newSiteTitle

as a note. Set-PnPWeb is the command that changes the title and then reverts back. the behavior is you see the changed title on the actual site. in the Admin portal nothing ever changes. on refresh after a few min the actual site title reverts back.

For me works the following PATCH method
PATCH /v1.0/sites/{site_id}
{
    "description": "new description",
    "displayName": "newName"
}

From my testing, the description is changed immediately, but for site name, it takes few minutes until I see new name

Hey, I am curious. I tried this. It updates the displayname that shows up on the top left of the sharepoint site then after a few more refreshes reverts back. I never see any updates in the sharepoint admin portal. Did you experience anything like that?
